# "≥" or "≤" symbol in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, arithmetic-expressions

I am plotting a graph with ggplot2 and I want to put arithmetic symbols in the legend labels (or anywhere else for that matter) such as "≥". I've tried the coding line `expression(x>=y)` which works well, but I don't want the character before or after the "≥". For example, with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$carb <- factor(mtcars$carb)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, group=carb)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour=carb), size=4) + 
    scale_colour_discrete(labels=c(expression(x>=y), "2", "3", "4", "6", "8"))
```

I get this

[image]

but I want this.

[image]

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `phantom()>=y`   ..

Comment: `NULL>=y` will work also.